# How to Check Locked Tables in Sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How to Find Out the Locked Table
My Table Names 
1.lnhd,2.lnsh

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_find_oracle_locked_objects.htm

Answer (score 1):

Table which contains all the details are "v$session & v$locked_object". For more details check [this.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223)